# Remove JSON object from json array in mysql

Tags: mysql, json-extract, json-remove

I have a column that saves JSON string and I want to get rid of "zipcode" for that JSON object. How can I achieve that using MySQL functions?

```
{name:"Alex", "address": [
 {"type": "primary", "street": "bakers street", "zipcode": 90001},
 {"type": "secondary", "street": "honor street", "zipcode": 90002}
]
}
```

I tried this one
`select JSON_REMOVE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(@payload_json,'$. address'), '$[0]'),'$. zipcode')`
but it results like

````
     {"type": "primary", "street": "bakers street",},
     {"type": "secondary", "street": "honor street", "zipcode": 90002}
    ]
    }``` 

> Is there a way I could do it all at once?
````

Comment: Please add your trials and findings to the question.

Comment: I used 
```update user_info ui
set ui.info_json = JSON_REMOVE(info_json, '$. zipcode');```

Comment: You cannot access the JSON key-value pairs using SQL, it is just a string to it. You will need to update the whole JSON string but without the `zipcode`.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @AhmedHammad can you post an example of how to do it?

Comment: I tried this one ```select json_remove(JSON_EXTRACT(json_extract(@payload_json,'$. address'), '$[0]'),'$. zipcode')```  and it works but I would need to run a loop to update all the object in the array is there a way I could do all at once??